# Stack post fix parsing

Tags: c++

I'm trying to parse the following expression, but I always get negative values, due to char int conversion.
I tried to parsed the string one by one, and push pop from the stack, but don't know from where I get the negative values.
Would someone tell me where is the big

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<cmath>
#include <vector>
#include <stack>
using namespace std;


int main() {

    string S = "13+62*7+*";
    stack<char> s;
    for (int i = 0; i < S.size(); i++)
    {   

        if (S[i] == '+' && !s.empty())
        {   
            int d1 = (int)s.top() -'0';
            s.pop();
            int d2 = (int)s.top()-'0';
            s.pop();
            int sum = d1 + d2;
            s.push(sum);
        }
        else if (S[i] == '*' &&!s.empty())
        {
            int d1 = (int)s.top() - '0';
            s.pop();
            int d2 = (int)s.top()-'0';
            s.pop();
            int mul = d1 * d2;
            s.push(static_cast<char>(mul));
        }
        else
        {
            s.push(S[i]);

        }
    }


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Time for some _debugging_!

Comment: Your code could never work correctly for any number that has more than one digit.

Comment: I did debug, the value 4,6,2 is on the stack, then multiply is 12, when 12 is poped, it poped as negative number

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie There will be only one digit, that's a constraint in the puzzle

Comment: @andreahmed `"13+62*7+*"` -- *There will be only one digit* -- Huh?  How many digits are there in the numbers `13` and `62`?

Comment: @andreahmed -- *I did debug.  The value 4,6,2 is on the stack, then multiply is 12, when 12 is poped, it poped as negative number* -- That is not debugging, that is observing.  There was no "12" in the stack, since obviously a `stack<char>` can only hold one character per slot.  That's why I stated that your program as it stands cannot work for a multidigit number.

Comment: @andreahmed How do you plan to cast 12 to char when pushing to stack?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie 2*6 is 12, it's pushed then to stack, when addition comes, it pops it

Comment: @MiljenMikic Got it, that's the problem then.. how would one solve it :)

Comment: @andreahmed *it's pushed then to stack,* -- Then why is your test data `13+62*7+*`?  This is why you're having an issue -- you're confused as to what can be placed in the stack, and you're giving yourself invalid test data.  As stated, your stack has no way of figuring out what `13` and `62` are.

Comment: What would make much more sense is if you had a `std::stack<std::string>`, build up the number by concatenating the digit with whatever is on top of the stack.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie It's not invalid test data, that data is correct and I should come up with an algorithm that solves it, the out come should be 79

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Can you post an answer ? it's not a homework by the way, it's a puzzle in codailitiy

Comment: @andreahmed You mean 76? :)

Comment: @MiljenMikic yes

Comment: @andreahmed -- Why not change to `std::stack<std::string>` and work out the details from there?  I don't think it is fair to post answers to external Q/A sites here -- maybe suggestions, but not outright post code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is in this line:

```
  s.push(static_cast<char>(mul));
```

When you get a result of multiplication greater than 9, the attempt to cast it to char produces unexpected results.

The solution is usually to use two separate stacks, one for operands (it will contain integers) and other for operators (it will contain chars). Since you only push operands to stack, just change the type of stack from char to int and remove cast to char before pushing to stack and subtracting ‘0’ after popping from stack.

Comment: Can you formulate your idea into a code please :)  Thanks a lot

Comment: How would I maintain the two stacks ?